# Know a good templated ASP.Net Calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm looking to find a decent calendar control for an ASP.Net application that allows each day to have an "ItemTemplate" type of declaration so that I can list things that are happening within each day. Something like the Club Starter Kit, only more robust and that can handle other datasources besides DataSets and DataTables.

I'm thinking about fixing that control to handle other types of datasources, but would much rather go with something better if I can find one. I'd even be able to work with some kind of client side "calendar" if one was available.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a DatePicker control or something like the Calendar Extender. I'm looking for something that has full templates available for each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually ended going with the calendar control out of the Club Starter Kit (http://clubstarterkit.codeplex.com/) as the updated versions did what we needed them to do.

Answer (score 0):

[BaseCalendar](http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/) may work (you can customize everything).